# I want to use the ADetailer API

Tags: typescript, python-requests, payload, stable-diffusion

The following parameters were written so that the API of ADetailer, an extension of Stable Diffusion, can be used with i2i.

```
  params = {
    ...sdParameters,
    init_images: [image.toString("base64")],
    denoising_strength: denoisingStrength,
    width: adjustWidth,
    height: adjustHeight,
    alwayson_scripts: {
      ADetailer: {
        args: [
          {
            ad_model: "face_yolov8n.pt",
            ad_mask_max_ratio: 0.03,
            ad_denoising_strength: denoisingStrength,
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

However, when we ran i2i with these parameters, ADetailer did not work.
I would like to know if there is anything wrong with the parameters I have written regarding ADetailer, and if so, please correct it and let me know.
The denoisingStrength is an array of 4 keys and values, all 4 set to different DS values.

I would also like to know how to write parameters for ADetailer.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.All I had to do was add a double quotation.